# [Windows Driver Development]How to Disable F8 during the boot process of Windows?

Tags: windows, security, kernel, device-driver

Microsoft ENFORCE all kinds of kernel drivers running under Windows 7 64-bit must be signed by VeriSign. This is a vital feature to keep OS integrity.

However, there remains an only backdoor: If the user presses F8 during the boot process, then the user can choose an option to allow unsigned drivers to be loaded.

I know the backdoor is indispensable for driver development and testing; but for general users, this option is not only useless but also dangerous. For example, a malicious guy can intrude an encrypted system and intercept decrypted data via an unsigned filter driver.

If there is a way for the administrator to disable F8, then the backdoor will be blocked perfectly. To my knowledge, however, currently Microsoft offers no way to do this.

This page ( http://guino.home.insightbb.com/nosafefaq.html ) says their NoSafeMode.exe can do that. I tested NoSafeMode.exe and found it indeed can do that.

I am really very curious how NoSafeMode.exe does that. I am astounded by their declarations as follows:

> (1) Does it modify my Operating System Files? NO. This tool was
>   designed to be 100% legal and as such, it does not modify, edit,
>   replace or remove any operating system files.
>
> (2) Does it modify my Operating System Settings? NO. This tool was
>   designed to work independent of Operating System settings and as such,
>   it does not modify, edit, replace or remove any settings or registry
>   data.
>
> (3) How long does the Lock/Unlock process take? The Lock/Unlock
>   process takes merely seconds, and can be automated by using of command
>   line parameters for your convenience.
>
> (4) How long does the Lock protection last? The Lock will remain in
>   place indefinitely until you choose to unlock it or until you
>   completely re-install the Operating System on the machine.
>
> (5) Does it use any memory or hard disk space? NO. This tool simply
>   sets up your computer in a one-time process after which you don’t need
>   to have it running or even saved in the computer for it to continue
>   working. In fact I recommend you do not leave a copy of the software
>   in the machine in order to prevent attempts to remove the Lock from
>   the machine.

I don't intend to advertise the tool. I just want know how to program to disable F8 as NoSafeMode.exe does.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is related to windows kernel development. So I think it should not be regarded as off topic.

Comment: Windows built-in tool bcdedit.exe is not the solution.

Comment: Re: "For example, a malicious guy can intrude an encrypted system and intercept decrypted data via an unsigned filter driver." Then put the encrypted system in a safe or something. If someone obtains physical access to the protected system, you have already lost.

Comment: @In silico, this is another question. Some encryption systems can solve the problem you propose. In another example, consider an Internet bar, disabling F8 to prevent the user from compromising the machine is very conducive to maintenance.

Comment: The F8 thing only works during the boot process. If you want users of an Internet bar to not use F8 in that manner, then don't allow them to shut down or restart the computer in the first place (which is what you want anyway). Make the shutdown/restart process an administrator-only procedure, and set up group policies and guest accounts so that your patrons can't do bad things to the machine. That is a much more comprehensive solution anyway.

Comment: Just run it in a debugger and see what it does.

Comment: Removing the battery or unplugging the power cord is hardly an administrator only procedure, and it is guaranteed to reboot the computer. I agree that once physical access is obtained, you lost. The OP thread model might be protecting abuse from regular user (like a corporate laptop used on the road).

Comment: Get a tool like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and read the boot sector before and after. Maybe it loads a good old "DOS" keyboard driver hook that filters out F8. Windows replaces it with its own during boot, making the F8 available again afterwards.